# ASP Membership Current user not taking the right value

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-membership

i am using an ASP control Login and i want to redirect the user logged in depending on its role. But it seems like The User take the previous value of the last logged in user. seems problem of refresh the current user or something like this 
Code of  my webform1.aspx.cs:

```
 protected void Login1_LoggedIn(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        TextBox1.Text = Context.User.Identity.Name.ToString();
        if (Context.User.IsInRole("admin"))
        {
            Response.Redirect("~/admin.aspx");
        }
        else if (User.IsInRole("user"))
        {
            Response.Redirect("~/user.aspx");
        }

    }
```

Comment: no one to help me on this point

Answer (score 0):

Inside `LoggedIn` event of `Login` control, principal object hasn't been attached to the current `HttpContext` yet.

Therefore, you cannot use `Context.User` inside `LoggedIn` event.

```
protected void Login1_LoggedIn(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   var roles = Roles.GetRolesForUser(Login1.Username);
   if (roles.Contains("admin"))
   {
      Response.Redirect("~/admin.aspx");
   }
   else if (User.IsInRole("user"))
   {
      Response.Redirect("~/user.aspx");
   }
}
```